# Reading the XMl Response and Extracting the nodes using c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to extract the XML Response from an API. My XML response looks like below. I tried different methods. can you please help me in reading and extracting the individual nodes from the XMl response.

For Example: I want to extract  node from below XML response.

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<RichDBDS><TrxDetailCard><TRX_HD_Key>5437845</TRX_HD_Key>   <Invoice_ID>189809</Invoice_ID><Date_DT>3/24/2016 1:34:44 PM</Date_DT><Merchant_Key>2202</Merchant_Key><Reseller_Key>2</Reseller_Key><TUser_Name_VC>ITSTEST.ISMI</TUser_Name_VC><Processor_ID>CC Processor</Processor_ID><TRX_Settle_Key></TRX_Settle_Key><Tip_Amt_MN></Tip_Amt_MN><Approval_Code_CH>24032016013444</Approval_Code_CH><Auth_Amt_MN>184.99</Auth_Amt_MN><IP_VC>66.55.53.68</IP_VC><Account_Type_CH>MANUAL</Account_Type_CH><Last_Update_DT></Last_Update_DT><Orig_TRX_HD_Key></Orig_TRX_HD_Key><Settle_Date_DT></Settle_Date_DT><Settle_Flag_CH>FALSE</Settle_Flag_CH><Trans_Type_ID>Sale</Trans_Type_ID><Void_Flag_CH>FALSE</Void_Flag_CH><CustomerID></CustomerID><AVS_Resp_CH>Y</AVS_Resp_CH><CV_Resp_CH>M</CV_Resp_CH><Host_Ref_Num_CH>0b144718-3597-4cfb-a2b5-058679510f29</Host_Ref_Num_CH><Zip_CH>30328</Zip_CH><Acct_Num_CH>1111</Acct_Num_CH><Total_Amt_MN>184.99</Total_Amt_MN><Exp_CH>0917</Exp_CH><Name_on_Card_VC>Kenneth Boler</Name_on_Card_VC><Type_CH>VISA</Type_CH><Cash_Back_Amt_MN></Cash_Back_Amt_MN><Result_CH>0</Result_CH><Result_Txt_VC>approval</Result_Txt_VC><Trans_Status>Settled</Trans_Status><PO_Num></PO_Num></TrxDetailCard></RichDBDS>
```

Comment: What have you tried? And what are you trying to extract?  LINQ to XML would be a good option if you only need a few of things, XML serialisation might be a better fit if you require a representation of the entire message. This far, it doesn't look like you've done any research - perhaps have a read of [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try code like below using XML Linq.  I used Load(FILENAME or URL) method, but you can also use Parse(STRING).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var results = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "TrxDetailCard").Select(y => new {
               TRX_HD_Key = (int)y.Element(y.Name.Namespace + "TRX_HD_Key"),
               Invoice_ID = (int)y.Element(y.Name.Namespace + "Invoice_ID"),
               Date_DT = (DateTime)y.Element(y.Name.Namespace + "Date_DT"),
               Merchant_Key = (int)y.Element(y.Name.Namespace + "Merchant_Key")
            }).ToList();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried different methods as below, but for all the trials I am getting the result rendered as text.
XmlDocument xmlDocument123 = new XmlDocument();
XmlTextReader myXMLReader123 = null;
myXMLReader123 = new XmlTextReader(response2.GetResponseStream());
xmlDocument123.Load(myXMLReader123);

First method(using Xpath):
foreach (XmlNode xmlnode1 in xmlDocument123.SelectNodes("//string/RichDBDS/TrxDetailCard"))
 {                   
 Console.Out.WriteLine(xmlnode1.Value);

 }

Comment: Second method:
xmlDocument123.ChildNodes.Item(0).ChildNodes.Item(0).SelectNodes("TrxDetailCard").ToString()
In all above trials, I have the return type rendering as text data. I am not able to find particular node/element.

Comment: I'm not using straight xml, I'm using the enhanced Net Library XML Linq.  Try : XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(response2.GetResponseStream());